# NPPEN model in r

Tags: r

I would like to run a NPPEN model, however I found these code to learning but I got hooked at rasterization. Can someone tell me where things go wrong? Or is there any other way I can run a NPPEN model?

```
#
#
#     Test the NPPEN method from Beaugrand et al 2011
#
# (c) Copyright 2011 Jean-Olivier Irisson
#     GNU General Public License v3
#
#------------------------------------------------------------
pdf("nppen_plots.pdf")
set.seed(1234)
## Simulate data                                            {
# reference matrix
n = 1000
X = data.frame(T = rnorm(n, mean=5),S = 36+rnorm(n)#,
+ # bathy = rnorm(n, mean=300, sd=30)
+ )
# add some data in a given location of the state space
X2 = data.frame(
+ T = rnorm(n*3, mean=5),
+ S = 36+rnorm(n)#,
+ # bathy = rnorm(n, mean=300, sd=30)
+ )
X2 <- X2[X2$T>5.5 & X2$T<6.5 & X2$S<37 & X2$S>34.5,]
X <- rbind(X, X2)
# prediction matrix
m = 200
Y = data.frame(
+ T = rnorm(m, mean=5, sd=0.4),
+ S = 36+rnorm(m, sd=0.5)#,
+ # bathy = rnorm(m, mean=280, sd=10)
+ )
# Visualize the relative range of X and Y
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape")
# put all data in the same data.frame
Z <- rbind(data.frame(X, source="X"), data.frame(Y, source="Y"))
ggplot(Z) + geom_point(aes(x=T, y=S, colour=source), alpha=0.5)
# -> OK, Y is distributed within the distribution of X
# }
#source("nppen.R")
## Test rasterization                                       {
Xr <- rasterize(X, precision=c(0.2, 0.3))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘rasterize’ for signature ‘"data.frame",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPPEN model, rasterization issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950657/nppen-model-rasterization-issue)

Comment: but the question has not be answered yet, hopefully someone can help with this. Thanks

Comment: try installing the raster package.  library("raster")

Comment: I did instal raster , but still got the error message

Comment: Aren't you looking for this `rasterize` function: https://github.com/jiho/nppen/blob/master/nppen.R  It is taken from the same GitHub hosting the function you show in your question.

Comment: actually its the https://github.com/jiho/nppen/blob/master/NPPEN-test.R

Comment: @user5545418 it is the same: https://github.com/jiho/nppen  Just go back to the top of the GitHub repo.

Comment: Does it work now you use the correct `rasterize` function?

Comment: I tried to run it but I still have some problems , however, I am trying to edit , maybe I can solve it and post my results. Thanks

Comment: Yea the new function works, thanks Pascal